# Coin tossing game - probabilities of $(K,K,K)$ and $(Z,K,Z)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> Let's consider the following game of two players:
>
> A fair coin is tossed as long as no one has won. Player $A$ wins if the sequence $(Z,K,Z)$ appears and player $B$ wins if $(K,K,K)$ appears. What is the probability that $A$ wins?

(Note: To solve this problem we are only allowed to use the notion of conditional probability, law of total probability and bayes theorem!)

---

**My approach**:

Let be $P(A)$ the probability that $A$ wins. I am not sure how to tackle this problem in a rigorous way because I am not able to find an appropriate *probability space*. What I could do is assume that we are at some stage of the game where nobody has won. Then, we define two sets
\begin{align*}
&B_{K}:=\{\omega_1=K,\omega_2\in\{Z,K\},\omega_3\in\{Z,K\},\dots\}\\
&B_{Z}:=\{\omega_1=Z,\omega_2\in\{Z,K\},\omega_3\in\{Z,K\},\dots\}.
\end{align*}

Those two sets are obviously disjoint and all future sequences are either member of $B_{K}$ or $B_{Z}$. Further, we can easiliy see that there exists a bijection between both sets.

Is it correct if I simply define a sample space $\Omega$ which consists of all future sequences that either start with $K$ or $Z$? This would mean that $P(B_{K})+P(B_{Z})=1$ and $P(B_{K})=P(B_{Z})=0.5$ and allows us to apply the law of total probability
$$
P(A)=P(A\mid B_{K}) P(B_{K})+P(A\mid B_{Z}) P(B_{Z})=0.5\cdot(P(A\mid B_{K}) +P(A\mid B_{Z})).
$$

---

Is this the way to go? It doesn't feel rigorous because of two things.

1.) The sample space is only valid for some arbitrary stage of the game - not the whole game.

2.) How do I know that there exists a probability function which I can use? The sample space I have defined is not countable, so I don't know if I can assign a probability to each element of $\Omega$?

Comment: $K,Z$ are heads and tails?  I would do it with states, according to how much of a winning string (for either side) is ongoing.  Thus the active states would be $\emptyset$, $K$ (without a preceding $Z$) , $KK$, $Z$, $ZK$. The first two states can  only occur very early on in the game.

Comment: @lulu Yes $K$ denotes heads and $Z$ tails. It's a problem from a German lecture.

Comment: The $K$ I get, what's the $Z$ for?

Comment: @lulu $K=$ *Kopf* and $Z=$ *Zahl* which actually means integer.

Comment: Thanks.  Was my suggestion clear enough?  The idea here:  don't try to keep track of all possible paths which, after all, might be very long.  All we care about are the most recent throws, and there are very few cases to consider.  This approach, generally speaking, is due to Markov and it comes up a lot.

Comment: @lulu, I don't understand how your suggestion adresses my two concerns?

Comment: The sample space is the set of all binary sequences, but this isn't a great way to look at the problem.  As I said, it's perfectly possible that the path we take will be long, but that's irrelevant.  The only reason it's long is that we keep revisiting the same state(s) over and over, and there's no point keeping track of that.  For instance the path $KKZKKZKKZKKZ\cdots$ endlessly cycles through the states $KK,Z,ZK$.  It's enough to just think through how those states fit together.

Comment: If you truncate a sequence when a winner is determined, then the probability of that path is just $\frac 1{2^n}$, where $n$ is the length of the truncated sequence.  Truly infinite paths have probability $0$, as you would expect.

Comment: @lulu, how would you describe it mathematically if you model the game by revisitng the $4$ states?

Comment: By considering transitions.  The state $Z$, for instance, goes to $ZK$ or stays at $Z$, each with probability $\frac 12$.  Thus, if $P_S$ denotes the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that you are currently in state $S$, we have $P_Z=\frac 12\times (P_Z+P_{ZK})$.

Comment: @lulu doesn't this approach rely on Markov chains? Maybe your approach is faster but we are explicitly told to use conditional probabilties. So I thought that there must be some way to define an appropriate sample space which allows us to use conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Following Lulu's suggestion, let us first define the states  on last toss(es):
$S$ = starting toss, $\,A1\equiv$ first $Z$, $A2\equiv$  $ZK$, $\,B1\equiv$ first $K$, $\,B2\equiv KK$,

Then tracing movement step-by-step from one state to another, we have

$S =  .5A1+.5B1$

$A1=  .5A2 +.5A1$

$A2= .5*1 +.5B2\quad$ [Either we get ZKZ and are done, or go to $B2$]

$B1= .5B2+.5A1$

$B2= .5*0 +.5A1\;$ [We bar $KKK$ as we compute for $A$'s win ]

*Note that these equations involve using conditional probabilities*

Solving these equations, we get $S = P(A\;wins)=\frac7{12}$

As a countercheck,
if we exchange the multiplier $1$ and $0$ in the equations for $A2$ and $B2$,
we get P(B wins) $= \frac5{12}$

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about it after deleting the answer which computed the number of tosses needed instead of the probabilities. Hope it is of use to you !

Comment: @Philipp: Happy New Year ! $\;\;$ :-)